# Spark tuning issues

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

[image: spark performance tuning]

**strong text**
Why this stage has been running with 1 thread at end ? Due to this it is taking much time to finish, I guess here it is not achieving parallel process.

So can any one explain it ?

Comment: This is quite broad. Do you care sharing more information or an MVCE so someone can provide some help ?

Comment: It is helpful here sometimes to see the DAG which spark executes in order to process a certain stage which are the building blocks of jobs. In the UI go to the currently executed stage and click on "DAG Visualization".

Comment: Looks like option "spark.executor.cores" value is 1. If one core is used, tasks executed one by one, not in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

As you haven't put any more specific information about what exactly are you trying to do there can be only broad answer.

Most common cause if you have one (or just a few) tasks hanging in larger pool of tasks is [skewed data](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/skew-join.html).

Another option is that the data triggered task that might be taking longer to compute the data (CPU heavy)

Or your task is hanging on IO which might indicate network/IO channel saturation.

Answer (score 0):

The question is pretty generic. Spark documentation says that it is not really easy to find bottlenecks directly or indirectly even for smallest of the programs (such as WordCount). The bottleneck can be in IO, memory to CPU, CPU where Garbage collection is going on, network and other factors internal to spark (such as scheduler delays, buffer memory overflows etc).

So, you might need to dig deeper keeping the below in mind:

a. Do you have many cores freely available to share the load of the stage.
b. How many executors are configured for this job to finish
c. is the 200GB data read/write justified for the job that you are doing.
d. free RAM on server before job trigger.
e. Go to YARN resource manager to see the resources around memory and CPU cores (in case you are using YARN).